# Set Subversion root directory for access via svn+ssh

Tags: svn, macos, version-control

I'm having trouble setting Subversion's root folder for repositories. The path has gotten pretty long and I'd like to shorten it to "/".

We currently access Subversion from clients via:

**svn+ssh://server.domain.com/Library/Subversion/Repositories/project/trunk**

and would like to shorten URL to:

**svn+ssh://server.domain.com/project/trunk**

I've tried:

```
server:~ admin$ svnserve -r /Library/Subversion/Repositories
You must specify exactly one of -d, -i, -t or -X.
Type 'svnserve --help' for usage.
```

I've also tried the **-t** flag since access via ssh it technically tunneling:

```
server:~ admin$ svnserve -t -r /Library/Subversion/Repositories/
( success ( 2 2 ( ) ( edit-pipeline svndiff1 absent-entries commit-revprops depth log-revprops partial-replay ) ) )
```

but I get that criptic response and the cursor waiting as if it's expecting more input?!?

Anyone know how to set this?

Answer (score -1):

The Subversion documentation says this about the `-t` flag:

> This flag is automatically passed for you by the client when running over a tunnel agent such as ssh. That means there's rarely any need for you to pass this option to svnserve.

I think you're probably looking just to run the server as a daemon:

```
svnserve -d -r /Library/Subversion/Repositories/
```

Comment: Thanks but my understanding of connecting via svn+ssh is that the connection is "tunneled" via ssh. From the same svn documentation you quoted: "The important thing to understand here is that the Subversion client is not connecting to a running svnserve daemon. **This method of access doesn't require a daemon, nor does it notice one if present**. It relies wholly on the ability of ssh to spawn a temporary svn- serve process, which then terminates when the network connection is closed." So I don't think -d is going to work in my case...which is why I gave -t a shot to see if it *might* work.